# SqlPlus does't execute in a batch loop, why?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I made a batch script that iterates recursively through all the .sql files under a directory. My problem is that i can echo all the files treated correctly with this version :

```
 @for /r "%PWD%\06-Instalaciones" %%a in (*.sql) do (IF "C:%%~pa" NEQ "%PWD%06-Instalaciones\ProximaInstalacion\" echo %%~fa )
```

But i cant seem to sucessfully call SqlPlus instead of the echo, for every sql file treated :

```
@for /r "%PWD%\06-Instalaciones" %%a in (*.sql) do (IF "C:%%~pa" NEQ "%PWD%06-Instalaciones\ProximaInstalacion\" %ORACLE_HOME%/bin/sqlplus -L -S FOO/BAR@%sid% @%%~fa)
```

I get the following error : "(HOST was unexpected at this time.".

Thank you.

Comment: Try writing `echo` before `%ORACLE_HOME%/bin/...`, to see what the command expands to, and if there is a parameter with spaces that needs quoting.

Comment: I tried what u said and the %%~fa aint expanding. If need to wrap the whole SqlPlus call in quotes for it to work, but then SqlPlus doesnt execute.

Comment: Try using another letter, for example `%%G`, since `%~fa` already has the meaning _filename_ + _attributes_.

Comment: I can't expand %%G,if i repeat the echoing and quoting process i get %G.

Comment: I tried with %%f :                                                        @for /r "%PWD%\06-Instalaciones" %%f in (*.sql) do (IF "C:%%~pf" NEQ "%PWD%06-Instalaciones\ProximaInstalacion\" %ORACLE_HOME%/bin/sqlplus -L -S FOO/BAR@%sid% @%%~f >> log.txt)

Comment: Man you were right, one of my variables had a space. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to angus for pointing out my error. I had a space in one of my variables!!! Particularly in %sid%. I'll leave here my code in case someone needs it :

```
@echo off
@SET PWD=%~dp0
@SET sid=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SID=xxxxx))) 
@for /r "%PWD%\06-Instalaciones" %%f in (*.sql) do (IF "C:%%~pf" NEQ "%PWD%06-Instalaciones\ProximaInstalacion\" %ORACLE_HOME%/bin/sqlplus -L -S FOO/BAR@"%sid%" @%%~f >> log.txt)
```